# how can i get first record of my custom adapter to ListView and next record by buttonClick

Tags: android, xml, listview, android-adapter

xml of activity :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
    tools:context="com.example.aref.teachingtorkmanlanguage.MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:dividerHeight="12dp">
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

xml of item :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/imgView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/sib"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnBack"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_black_24dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnForward"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_arrow_forward_black_24dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/word"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btnBack"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/btnBack"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/btnForward"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/btnForward"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/mean"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/btnForward"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:gravity="center"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

show :

[xml of item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/he52E.png)

i want get first record of my adapter in listview and navigate between items by back button and forward button ...
how can i do this ?
..................................................................

Comment: What do you mean by navigate when your items are shown in listView?

Comment: If you are using an adapter you can have some reference like position to get the first item of the adapter. is it correct? So the first position is 0

Answer (score 1):

you can use ViewPager in this case as it allows the user to flip left and right through pages of data.

```
 <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Create your adapter class, pass data to adapter and set the adapter on viewpager like below

```
  mCustomPagerAdapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(context, data);

    mViewPager.setAdapter(mCustomPagerAdapter);
```

You can refer to https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html and http://www.journaldev.com/10096/android-viewpager-example-tutorial link for more details.